# RSpec double - stub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, double

I am new to rspec. I am using a receive_message_chain and stubbing method chains and its working fine now.

Code being tested

```
Abc::ImportJob < ImportBaseJob
   
   def self.perform
     base_class_meth(param1, param2)
   end
end
```

Abc::ImportBaseJob

```
def base_class_meth(param1, param2)
 Book.to_be_published.find_each do |book|
    publish_report(book)
  end
end

def publish_report(book)
  Publishjob.perform
end
```

end

rspec

```
before do
   allow(Book).to receive_message_chain(:to_be_published, :find_each).and_yield(book1)
end
```

Now I am trying to get rid of the receive_message_chain and use double here.

Code using double:

```
before do
  books_to_be_published = double('books_to_be_published')
  allow(Book).to receive(:to_be_published).and_return('books_to_be_published')
  allow(books_to_be_published).to receive(:find_each).and_yield(book1)
end

it 'should publish kafka message at event start' do
    expect(PublishJob).to receive(:new).with(book1)
    ABC::ImportJob.perform
  end
```

But the result is
expected 1 time with argument
received: 0 times

What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: What is `dispatch_ev1`? It’s not mentioned in your code extracts. If you leave out the argument and check just for the method, i.e., `expect(PublishJob).to receive(:new)`, is there any difference?

Comment: Updated the question. Its not dispatch_ev1, its book1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't it be

```
allow(Book).to receive(:to_be_published).and_return(books_to_be_published)
```